# Обработка исключений указанных в сигнатуре функции

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

Есть ли способ заставить компилятор (g++) ругаться на необработанное исключение (возможно, какой-то флаг) при использовании функции типа

`void f() throw (std::logic_error) {...}`  ?

Upd.: неактуально, потому что данная конструкция [помечена](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec) как *устаревшая*

Спасибо за комментарий @ixSci

**UPD.** https://habr.com/post/430690/

Comment: Ругаться через какое расстояние стека? Я если логика проги ловить только в `main`? Именное исключение предназначено именно для того, чтобы их фильтровать и не ловить.

Comment: Спецификаций исключений нет в стандарте начиная с C++14 (deprecated с C++11), Вы знаете об этом? Их убрали потому, что они нигде (i) не работали.  (i) может _где-то как-то_ и работали.

Comment: @ixSci, да, буквально только что об этом мне сказали в тг-чатике ))

Comment: @ixSci, но за комментарий - спасибо!

Comment: @AlexGlebe, я бы ожидал ошибки в месте вызова.

Comment: На самом деле было же предложение сделать исключения частью сигнатуры функции и соответственно заставить компилятор проверять их во время компиляции. Однако разум не победил и теперь в языке фактически нет никаких средств для проверки исключений, нельзя даже сказать, бросаются ли исключения внутри функции или нет. Собственно это один из основных аргументов против использования исключений.

Comment: Как раз победил разум. Потому что иначе пришлось бы либо прописывать все исключения (а компилятору проверять и проверять) и на это бы все забивали (как собственно почти везде в жаве и делают), либо просто никто  бы не использовал. Но придумали noexcept, который более практичен, не ломает обратную совместимость и как бы помогает в оптимизации.

Comment: @KoVadim Вам что, нравится текущая ситуация, когда исключения приходится прописывать и проверять вручную? Почему не возложить проверку на компилятор? По-вашему же как раз выходит, что победили забивальщики, а не разум. И обратная совместимость как раз никак бы не ломалась, зато было бы идентифицировано множество проблемных мест, а вот `noexcept` малого того, что крайне неудачно назван, так и именно он ломает обратную совместимость, а необходимость конструкций вроде `int foo()noexcept(noexcept(function_body)) { function_body; }` иначе как трешем назвать не могу.

Comment: Не ясно, о чем вопрос. О каком именно "предупреждении компилятора" идет речь? Предупреждение о том, что  функция `f` выбрасывает изнутри исключения, которые она не должна выбрасывать? Или предупреждение о том, что внешняя (вызывающая) функция не обрабатывает исключения, которые могут "вылететь " из `f`?

Comment: @VTT я не знаю, где Вы достали такие конструкции. Но что то отдалённо подобное я видел только в шаблонной магии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы бы ожидали ошибки, а логика исключений по типу предназначена именно для фильтрации. Одна функция обрабатывает одни ошибки, другие что выше - по другому пашут. Данные пример показывает как сортировать разные исключения. И ваше пожелание выдать ошибку тут не в тему.

```
# include <iostream>

void g()throw(int){
  std::cout<<"g:throwing int "<<1<<std::endl; 
  throw int(1); }

void h()throw(char){
  std::cout<<"h:start"<<std::endl; 
  if(false)throw char('1'); }

void f(){
  std::cout<<"f:start"<<std::endl; 
  try{
    h();
    g();}
  catch(char c){
    std::cout<<"f:catch char "<<c<<std::endl;}  }

int main(){
  std::cout<<"main:start"<<std::endl; 
  try {    f();    }
  catch(int x){
    std::cout<<"main:catch int "<<x<<std::endl;}
  catch(...){
    std::cout<<"main:catch ? "<<std::endl;}
  std::cout<<"main:end"<<std::endl; }
```

Функция `main` поймала исключение , а `f` игнорировала. Так всё и задумано.

```
main:start
f:start
h:start
g:throwing int 1
main:catch int 1
main:end
```

Comment: Да, все, спасибо, теперь стало понятно, о чем идет речь. Спасибо за объяснение!

Comment: Не понял этого ответа. Каким образом спецификация исключений связана с тем, кто поймал, а кто игнорировал исключение?

Comment: @AnT вопрос был почему нет у компилятора предупреждения, что отдел `try/catch` не обрабатывает ВСЕ возможные исключения. Я ответил, что программист имеет право НЕ обрабатывать исключения, что ему не в тему.

Answer (score 1):

Динамические спецификации исключений являются deprecated.

Современные спецификации исключений свелись просто к `noexcept`. Начиная с C++17 `noexcept` является частью типа функции. Но по-прежнему не запрещается использовать `throw` внутри `noexept` функций и вызывать бросающие исключения функции из `noexept` функций. Поведение осталось прежним - попытка выбросить исключение из `noexept` функции приводит к вызову `std::terminate`.

Многие компиляторы выдают предупреждение при обнаружении необработанного `throw` в `noexcept` функции.